# Try to remove the URL that's not my domain name in google search result?

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js, google-search

I have 3 website: website-1.com, website-2.com and website-3.com.
When I type "site:website-1.com" it's show something like "example.website-1.com" in google search result.

Anyone know how to remove it ("example.website-1.com") from search result.